# Trouble with reformatting Access date SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column [Activity Period] and it's 6 digits that comprise a yearmonth date (eg 201601). My query:

```
UPDATE [Consolidated]
Set [Activity Period] = Left([Activity Period],4) & "/" & Right([Activity Period],2)
```

which works find for inserting a slash in between the month and the year. The field, however, is still formatted as text.

When I tried to change it manually under the field settings it adds in a "1" for the day, so 201601 becomes 2016/01/01, etc. I would like to format it to just month and year.

Comment: *I would like to format it to just month and year* ... afaik - there is no date or datetime format in any relational database with just month/year data points.

Comment: Do you know why that might be? 

I find it odd since Excel has this capability and the two can speak to each other directly.
I obviously concede to your experience as I'm very new to this, it just seems very strange.

Comment: A date is always a date. You can format it as you like e.g. MM/YYYY but a) the source date remains a date and b) the formatted output is a string (text).

Comment: Check again in Excel. Month / Year is a *Custom* format, not *Date* format. In fact, as soon as you enter "06/2018", Excel automatically adds a day = 1 as cell value: "06/01/2018" though it appears as "Jun-18". (US day first format).

Comment: So forgive my ignorance here then, but what is my best way to go about displaying the month and the year? Should I just leave it as a text?

Comment: I believe since it's a date, it should remain a date. Change only the field format to `"YYYYMM"`.

Comment: Apologies; not sure how to do that in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the current field to, say, `[Old Activity Period]` and create new field of data type Date. Apply a format of yyyy/mm.

Then run this query:

```
UPDATE [Consolidated]
Set [Activity Period] = CDate(Left([Old Activity Period],4) & "/" & Right([Old Activity Period],2))
```

Comment: `dateserial(left([Old Activity_Period], 4), right([Old_Activity_Period], 2), 1)` would also work (either in this UPDATE statement or in a query where you were keeping the old column and not adding a new one.

Comment: I tried to update the current one and it returned a missing operator in the first half of the stateemnt

Comment: You can't update "the current one" without first to modify it as explained.

Comment: I did what you told me to (renamed and made new) and ran the query. It asked me to:

enter parameter value: (old activity period)

Comment: Then "old activity period" is not the name of the renamed field.

Comment: Forgot to save the table... apologies for my naivety. Did so and ran it again and it said that it can't run due to data validation rules.

Hang on, I'm legitimately incompetent. I had the format in the wrong field.\

Comment: Okay, I did exactly what I was told this time haha. Now it displays as "yyyy/mm" in the field and I have to click on it to see, and it's automatically adding a 1 for the day for every date

Comment: Yes, you can't have a date with no day. But, anywhere where you wish to display that value, apply the format _yyyy/mm_.